# moto e not power on after update

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, power-on, motorola-moto-e

While updating from KitKat 4.4.2 to 4.4.4 my moto e switched off.

During this process, the battery level was less than 50%. I've tried charging and nothing happened but if I press the power button while charging the notification LED blinks.

Please help me to fix this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the stock charger? Is there a possibility that the charger isn't working?

Comment: @1990clb Yes I am using stock charger. It used to charging other mobile.